# Several same generic classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class of `<T>`, that can notify the subscribed object.

```
public class SimpleEvent<T>
{
    private event Action<T> listeners;

    private T storedValue;

    public void AddListener(Action<T> listener, bool notifySender = false)
    {
        listeners += listener;

        if (notifySender && storedValue != null)
            listener?.Invoke(storedValue);
    }
}
```

But if I want to do a generic class of `<T, Y>` with the same principle of operation, I need to copy & paste the entire code with minor changes. How can I avoid this?

Generic class of `<T, Y>` looks pretty similar, but I think it could be better.

```
public class SimpleEvent<T, Y>
{
    private event Action<T, Y> listeners;

    private T TValue;
    private Y YValue;

    public void AddListener(Action<T, Y> listener, bool notifySender = false)
    {
        listeners += listener;

        if (notifySender && (TValue != null && YValue != null))
            listener?.Invoke(TValue, YValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: What you want is a _higher kinded-type_, which C# and .NET does not support as they don't support (amongst other things) variadic generics or templates. The only real workaround is to use `Action<T,Y>` where `Y` is a value-tuple, and require additional arguments to be passed through `Y`.

Comment: ...which is kinda like how `EventHandler<TArgs> where TArgs : EventArgs` works, so you're just reinventing that...

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just use a value tuple, i.e. `SimpleEvent<(T, Y)>`.

I would assume you also have some way to change the stored value, and want to raise the event at that point. If you only want set one of the values you could perhaps use an extension method. Something like

```
 public static SetItem1<T1, T2>(this SimpleEvent<T1, T2> self, T1 value) 
     => self.Set((value, self.StoredValue.Item2));
```

Note that you should provide some way for users of your class to un register event handlers. Either by an explicit RemoveListener-method, or by returning an IDisposable from your AddListener-method.